# What is the computational complexity of arima() function in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

If my time series has `n` members and I want to fit `ARIMA(1,0,1)` model, what will be the complexity in big `O` notation?

In the following example I need to know the complexity of second line of code:

```
series <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,1), ar=.9, ma=-.5), n=1000)
result <- arima(series, order=c(1,0,1))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is `O(n)` complexity. A story for this? See below.

As I said in the comment, we can measure it by a regression model. As a toy demonstration, consider the following procedure for data collection and regression.

We first define a function to measure model fitting time of an `ARMA(1,1)` model (or `ARIMA(1,0,1)`). *(Note that I am using the basic `system.time()` here. You may consider using `microbenchmark()` from package `microbenchmark`. But in the following, I will use reasonably large `n`, to reduce the sensitivity in time measuring.)*

```
t_arma <- function(N) {
  series <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,1), ar=.9, ma=-.5), n=N)
  as.numeric((system.time(arima(series, order=c(1,0,1)))))[3]
  }
```

We need to collect, say 100, data. We try 100 increasingly large `n`, and measure the model fitting time `t`.

```
k <- 100; t <- numeric(k)
n <- seq(20000, by = 1000, length = k)  ## start from n = 20000 (big enough)
for (i in 1:k) t[i] <- t_arma(n[i])
```

Now, if we assume the complexity is: `a * (n ^ b)`, or `O(n ^ b)`, we can estimate `a`, `b` by a regression model:

```
log(t) ~ log(a) + b * log(n)
```

and we are particularly interested in the slop estimate: `b`.

So let's call `lm()`

```
fit <- lm(log(t) ~ log(n))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)       log(n)  
#    -9.2185       0.8646
```

We can also sketch the scatter plot of `log(n)` v.s. `log(t)`, as well as the fitted line:

```
plot(log(n), log(t), main = "scatter plot")
lines(log(n), fit$fitted, col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image: fitted model]

**There are some outliers in the beginning, hence the slope is lower than it should be. We now consider removing outliers and refit model for robustness.**

Outliers are featured with large residuals. Let's have a look:

```
plot(fit$resi, main = "residuals")
```

[image: residuals]

We can mark and remove those outliers. Looks like `0.5` is a good enough threshold to filter those outliers.

```
exclude <- fit$resi > 0.5
n <- n[!exclude]
t <- t[!exclude]
```

Now we refit the linear model and make plot:

```
robust_fit <- lm(log(t) ~ log(n))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)       log(n)  
#    -11.197        1.039  

plot(log(n), log(t), main = "scatter plot (outliers removed)")
lines(log(n), robust_fit$fitted, col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Wow, great, we are golden! The slope estimate is 1. So the `O(n)` complexity is justified!

Comment: Hi, great answer. I'm wondering if there is a package or work to generalize this method, meaning like fitting various complexity functions to increasing size dataset, and find out which is relevant. THanks

Comment: @agenis Hi thanks for the message and sorry for the late reply. I don't know of a package that does this kind of things in a general context. It is a good idea to regress (log) computation time against (log) number of data and (log) number of parameters to estimate algorithmic complexity, but if the operation to be measured involves several stages with different complexity, the measurement of the overall complexity is not accurate.

Comment: Hi. THanks for your reply. I have been working on a piece of code to do empirical estimation of complexity relationship for time and memory, it's in the form of a package `GuessCompx`. Since you seem to have some technical background on the subject, would you be kind enough taking a look at this little work and tell me your thoughts about it? Thanks, It's here: https://github.com/agenis/GuessCompx